# setuptools with data in a folder above the tool folder

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a toolbox that has support in 2 languages, so the structure is as:

```
tool
| Python
    | setup.py
| MATLAB
| Common
    | some_data.ext
```

Now, `some_data.ext` is not small enough to consider having 2 copies of it, so it sits in the Common folder, where both languages can read it. But while MATLAB does not have a install process, python does, and thus when reading the data from the file, I loose its path (i.e. I can't open `./../../Common/some_data.ext` because after the python install the relative path does not work).

I read that you can use the [`datafiles`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) part of setuptools to add this data, but this only seems to work if the data is within a folder inside the Python package, not some folder "above" it.

Can I do this with setuptools? if so, how? If not, is there any alternative?

Comment: Think of it a different way: `setuptools` will treat everything at the source root as the root of the project, so that everything will be neatly map to its package directory inside `site-packages`.  How would this work for arbitrary remap up out through/escape the parent of that root? If this was possible it would open the avenue to allow malicious packages overwrite important files such as `/etc/passwd` trivially.

Comment: Another way to think about it: the way this is setup has a very tight coupling to some directory structure. Better design would not put any artificial constraint on where the file is at, but instead provide a manner to load from the environment.  This may be defined using an environment variable of some kind for the source data location.

Comment: @metatoaster right, that makes sense. I am trying to avoid to have extra steps in the installation process, so I'd kind of rather not make the user need to set up an environment variable etc, plus currently the tool is OS agnostic (well, as far as I tested it) so I am a bit cautious on setting up environment variables. Perhaps having `setup.py` manually search for the file (as the relative path to this python file will be valid) and then  making a copy of the file in the python folder before the install would work?  Is this a good plausible way of solving it?

Comment: Maybe? You haven't describe why you have a single project that has MATLAB code and Python code, nor any detail on whether or not the Python and MATLAB parts are interlinked.  If the code in these two projects are mutually dependent on each other you may wish to instead use something more agnostic to both projects to set up the working environment for your users. Packing the datafiles as part of an installable Python package may not be what you are after since you are directly coupling the paths into your project (since you note relatives paths not working).

Comment: Ah, you are right. The python code does nor use anything in MATLAB, its the same tool in 2 different languages, not a single project that uses 2 languages. So the code is not mutual dependent. The python code only needs the stuff in `/python` and some files in `/common` that tare compiled in the install process. So its possible that doing what I said will solve the issue, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to give the relative path, but provide where to put it:

```
  data_files=[('data', ['../Common/some_data.ext'])],
```

Comment: Note that this might not work if you distribute your project, i.e. if you publish _sdist_ or _wheel_ of your project. -- Maybe consider _symlinking_ that `.ext` file into a package of your Python project, this will feel much more natural than having dependencies in parent directories.